# message push from application server

Tags: android, spring, google-cloud-messaging

I am doing a mobile application which has front end android and back end spring with hibernate.Its a chat application where users are using android.What are the steps ,I need to follow.Please throw some light on this.I am using Google cloud messaging.

Comment: What you have done? You should consult the official documentation (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) first

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look in [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) like @Mohsen Afshin said also should take a look in :

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for network operation.

[BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to update the UI.